# Bootstrap calendar option

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker

I use a calendar to select dates for two types of inscription
for the first one all days are enabled for the second only sunday are enabled
if the code is like that how can i use the right one

```
if ($type==12){ daysOfWeekDisabled:[1,2,3,4,5,6],}
```

please some one help me

this is my code

```
$('#op_calender_inscription').datepicker({

    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",

    <?php if($operation->start !='00/00/0000'): ?>

    startDate: '<?php echo $operation->start ?>',
    if ($type == 12) 
    {daysOfWeekDisabled:[1,2,3,4,5,6],}

    <?php 

    endif;

    if($operation->end !='00/00/0000'): ?>

    endDate: '<?php echo $operation->end ?>',

    <?php endif; ?>

    multidate: true,
    multidateSeparator:";",

    calendarWeeks: true,

    language: 'fr'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using it with PHP right? then:

```
<?php if ($type == 12) : ?>
    {daysOfWeekDisabled:[1,2,3,4,5,6],}
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: think you this is the code
<script>
$('#op_calender_inscription').datepicker({

 format: "dd/mm/yyyy",

 <?php if($operation->start !='00/00/0000'): ?>

    startDate: '<?php echo $operation->start ?>',
    daysOfWeekDisabled:[1,2,3,4,5,6],
 <?php 

 endif;

 if($operation->end !='00/00/0000'): ?>

    endDate: '<?php echo $operation->end ?>',

 <?php endif; ?>

    multidate: true,
    multidateSeparator:";",

    calendarWeeks: true,

 language: 'fr'
</script>

Comment: where comes the $type from? is it PHP variable or JS?

Comment: i have 2 condition of inscription the first is enabled all days the second is enabled only sundays
and type==2 is php variable
but the code of disabled days is in js

Comment: Then you can use my answer above.